# How to set camera to user location in google maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have the code set so it loads up the map, however it doesn't automatically go to the user's location until they press the zoom button. I would prefer if it started at the users location or at least loaded it up within a few seconds of the map appearing.

Comment: I don't remember the callback methods of Google Maps but you can move the code that shows the location to `onMapReady()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in onMapready

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
        mMap.clear();

        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        mp.title("my position");

        mMap.addMarker(mp);
        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    }
});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**xml Code Add map like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Add java code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
map = ((SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this); //You can also use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER        
  }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
 }
```

**Add permissions in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

try this code it helps you